# flake8 (E902) TokenError in python format

Tags: python, python-3.x, flake8

I dont understand why i got a E902 flake8 Error.
The code is as follows:

```py
def mi_func(x):

    # Asignar los valores a una lista
    lista_massn = x['MASSN'].values.tolist()
    lista_flag = x['UFLAG'].values.tolist()

    # Obtener los valores unicos
    unique_list_massn = unique_values(lista_massn)
    unique_list_flag = unique_values(lista_flag

    # Reglas de negocio para indicar desviaciones
    if (
            (len(unique_list_massn) == 1)
            & (unique_list_massn[0] == 'XE')
            & (max(unique_list_flag) == 0)):
        result = True
    else:
        result = False

    return result
```

I think the problem is in the "if/else" statement.
I put the condition in several lines in order to satisfy the numbre of character <80 (flake8 E501).
Is there a way to put this "if/else" statement satifaying the both flake8 rules (flake8 E501 and E902)?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: As an unrelated style suggestion, use `and` rather than `&` when working with True/False; `&` is more of a mathematical operator, doing things like bitwise-and and set intersection, while `and` is intended for conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

E902 is a catchall for `SyntaxError`s (in this case a `TokenError`)

python or pypy give you a more useful SyntaxError in this case

```
$ python3 t.py 
  File "t.py", line 14
    & (max(unique_list_flag) == 0)))
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
$ pypy3 t.py 
  File "t.py", line 8
    unique_list_flag = unique_values(lista_flag
                                    ^
SyntaxError: parenthesis is never closed
```

after fixing that the code passes flake8:

```
$ flake8 t.py
$
```

---

disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of flake8